# Creating a single URL with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to create a single URL with htaccess? Below are examples of SELF URLs I need.

example:

localhost/blog (category)

localhost/frequently-asked-questions (content)

localhost/book (tag)

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
     
    RewriteRule ^(en|de|tr)/?$ ?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
    
    RewriteCond $1 !^(css|js|images|inc|lang)
    
    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9]+)$ article.php?url=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
    
    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$  article.php?caturl=$1&catid=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$  tag.php?tagurl=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It is possible, but you'd need _one_ PHP script and then determine in the script if the parameter is a tag, content or category. And hopefully you never get a tag named blog

Comment: Why not go with `localhost/tag/XYZ` and `localhost/category/XYZ`?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no "main" differences that can tell you that the requested URL point to specific type of content, I will suggest 2 approaches :

1.
Define prefixes for **category** and **tag** and **article** routes

```
RewriteRule ^/category/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$  article.php?caturl=$1&catid=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/tag/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$  tag.php?tagurl=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/article/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9]+)$ article.php?url=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

2. 

Redirect all url's to php script that will query DB and search the type of the content by the url

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9]+)$ content.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and then inside this **content.php** run queries against **categories** table,
if no matches so search in **tags** table... and so on...
until no matches redirect to 404 page.
After you find the relevant content type you can include the relevant php file to continue handle this request.